# How to make Array append and sort fast in tableView swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, tableview

I have a chat message tableView, and I want to load the messages.
Have any idea to let tableView reload messages fast?
I try to this function.
But I don't know how to do the better way.
Thanks.

```
var contents:[ChatroomMessage] = [ChatroomMessage]()

func loadMessages() {

    //I think remove and append are very cost time
    self.contents.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false) 
    self.chatroom.messages.forEach({ (id,message) in
        self.contents.append(message)
    })

    if contents.count == 0  {            
        return
    }

    self.contents.sort(by: { (a,b) in
        a.datetime < b.datetime
    })

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    if self.contents.count > 0 {
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: self.contents.count-1,section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
    }

}
```

Comment: From where you are calling 'loadMessages'? Best place is set a notification to call 'loadMessages' on every message receive. There will be no need to perform any operation like date if you are in foreground.

Comment: Do not *guess* which operations are slow. Use Instruments and *profile.*

Comment: Actually simply assigning the (sorted) array has the same effect as  *removing + appending*.

Answer (score 0):

In any chat is very rarely used `reloadData()` because you can have lot's of messages in chat view.

Instead, you should reload(relayout) specific item(or cell). Cause you should create difference of states. 
You can use any library for diffs (for example – https://github.com/wokalski/Diff.swift)

Also, you can use nMessenger(https://github.com/eBay/NMessenger), it's perfect. Messenger view based on AsyncDisplayKit(aka Texture) by Pinterest.

Comment: > In any chat is very rarely used reloadData() because you can have lot's of messages in chat view.  
technically yes, but the reason is not "many messages". we use `(reload/delete/insert)Rows` methods instead of `reloadData` because of nice animation and HIG, but not because of "reloadData takes much time with huge amount of items". `reloadData` updates only the visible part of ui.